# What is the default deployment location for spring boot application with embedded tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot

Does anybody know it ? I just want this information so that I may see how tomcat has delpoyed my application and it may help me to resolve some deployment problems earlier.

Thanks in advance for all responses.

Answer (score 8):

When you run spring boot project with embedded tomcat files are extracted under `/tmp` dir.
you can modify the path, changing from `/tmp` to other directory with `server.tomcat.basedir` property.

Comment: Where is bin folder